# Adding Powershell jobs to retrieve in parallel from paginated rest API

Tags: rest, pagination, powershell-3.0, jobs

I've spent perhaps over 30 hours trying to add various methods to implement parallel processing to my API call. The most obvious would be to place the code into a job, but I'm having no luck. Any ideas?

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Errorlog.txt"

$WondeObjectsArray = Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\WondeID.csv
$EndpointObjectArray = Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\Endpoints.csv

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("REDACTED", "REDACTED")

# School loop

Foreach ($object in $WondeObjectsArray) {
    $SchoolName = $object.School
    $TrustName = $object.Trust
    $WondeID = $object."Wonde ID"

# Create data structure
If(!(test-path "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName")) 
    {New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName" -ItemType Directory}
If(!(test-path "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName\$SchoolName")) 
    {New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName\$SchoolName" -ItemType Directory}


# Endpoint request loop 
foreach($Eobject in $EndpointObjectArray){
    $JsonName = $Eobject.JsonName
    $Table = $Eobject.Table
    $Method = $Eobject.Url_Method

# First response
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.wonde.com/v1.0/schools/$WondeID/$Table$Method&$Page" -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Body $body
    $concat = $response.data
#Pagination loop
While ($response.meta.pagination.next){
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $response.meta.Pagination.next -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Body $Body
    $concat = $concat + $response.data
} #pagination loop end

# Concatenate completed request
    $concat | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName\$SchoolName\$JsonName.json"

} # Endpoint request loop end
} # School loop end

Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I turned the code that I wanted to run in parallel into a scriptblock, Passed it the parameters by using param () And in the start job line I included my variables in -ArgumentList.

My issue was actually that when you start a new job it changes the script file path to C:/, when I was passing $PSScriptRoot rather than the default file location.

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Errorlog.txt"

$PathRoot = $PSScriptRoot
$WondeObjectsArray = Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\WondeID.csv
$EndpointObjectArray = Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot\Endpoints.csv

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("REDACTED", "REDACTED")

# School loop
Foreach ($object in $WondeObjectsArray) {
    $SchoolName = $object.School
    $TrustName = $object.Trust
    $WondeID = $object."Wonde ID"

# Create data structure
If(!(test-path "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName")) 
    {New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName" -ItemType Directory}
If(!(test-path "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName\$SchoolName")) 
    {New-Item -Path "$PSScriptRoot\$TrustName\$SchoolName" -ItemType Directory}

# Endpoint request loop 
foreach ($Eobject in $EndpointObjectArray){
    $JsonName = $Eobject.JsonName
    $Table = $Eobject.Table
    $Method = $Eobject.Url_Method

$scriptblock = {
param ($WondeID, $Table, $Method, $headers, $trustName, $SchoolName, $JsonName, $PathRoot)

write-host "$TrustName : $SchoolName : $JsonName is complete!"

# First response
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.wonde.com/v1.0/schools/$WondeID/$Table$Method&$Page" -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Body $body
    $concat = $response.data
#Pagination loop
While ($response.meta.pagination.next){
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $response.meta.Pagination.next -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers -Body $Body
    $concat = $concat + $response.data
} #pagination loop end

# Concatenate completed request
    $concat | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$PathRoot\$TrustName\$SchoolName\$JsonName.json"

}

Start-Job $scriptblock -Name "$SchoolName&$JsonName" -ArgumentList $WondeID, $Table, $Method, $headers, $trustName, $SchoolName, $JsonName, $PathRoot

} # Endpoint request loop end

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

Get-Job | Remove-Job 

} # School loop end

Stop-Transcript
```